# JMeter: How to ignore dynamic parameters in response assertions

Tags: jmeter

I have to ignore dynamic property value while cmpmarison. Can you please suggest how to do so. 
Currently I have used as 
(\d+)

And Pattern matching Rule as "Contains"

Can anyone please help on same

regards
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Given your current setup, if the response will contain **any number** - your assertion will pass, otherwise it will fail. You can use [Perl5-style regular expressions](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet) to handle dynamic response parts and static strings for doing the checks. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information.

The other approach is extracting the dynamic parts using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), converting them into JMeter Variables and using these variables in the Response Assertion. Regular Expression Extractor is executed **before** the assertion so this way you will be able to work it around in a more "transparent" way.

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for your reply... I have used Regular Expression Extractor. as Name : trans-id, Reference Name : trans-id ,  Regular Expression: <transaction-id>(.+?)</transaction-id>, Template: $1$   .... And I called this inside response assertion as <transaction-id>trans-id</transaction-id> ... But it fails.. Can you please suggest if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi .. It worked fine for me... I called it in wring way. When I called it as       <transaction-id>${trans-id}</transaction-id> .. it worked fine.

Comment: Hi From your first answer .. Given your current setup, if the response will contain any number - your assertion will pass, otherwise it will fail. ... Can you please suggest how to use it for String .. I have to ignore just dynamic values/string inside       <transaction-id>367</transaction-id> ... Please help

Comment: Hi Actually I have to ignore different dynamic parameters like purchase date, renewal date, timestamp, subscription-id, transaction-id etc. So it will be file instead of adding Regular Expression Extraction, directly ignore the parameters values.

Comment: Hi .. can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to ignore `367` but need to validate other bits use the following pattern: `<transaction-id>(.+?)</transaction-id>`. Similarly for other values. However I don't see a lot of sense in that form of testing, given you are not actually comparing expected values with the actual ones, what your assertion is doing? Assertions have their cost and should be used only when cannot be avoided, see [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for details.